# batch file how to filter filename start with certain character

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy a file if the filename is start with ABC0...(length not fixed),
But I use below code, it copy even my file name is like ABCUnit001 mean start with ABCU .

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
set filename=%%~nx


    if not "!filename=:~0,4!"=="ABC0" ( 
    copy "%%x" "destination path"
    move "%%x" "Destination path"
    )

)
```

Can any one help ? Thanks and appreciate

Comment: what's wrong with `copy abc0* "desination path"` ?

Comment: Hi Magoo, that is no wrong if copy the file with filename start with abc0 to destination path. But my problem is even my file name is ABCUnit001 mean start with ABCU. It also copy to destination path.

Comment: By default, every file has two names - the "long name" that you are using and a "short name" to make it compatible with the old DOS naming system. You can see both if you use `dir /X *.txt`. With your current problem, in order to use the `!var!` construct, yo need to insert `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` as the line before your `for` command

Comment: yup... I got add 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion' before my for loop. 
I checked using dir /X. My filename was correct.. Wonder why it will still copy wrongly...hmmm....

Comment: Why are you using the `NOT` option with the `IF` command if you want to copy files that start with `ABC0`?

Comment: If you want "to copy a file if the filename is start with ABC0" then `if not "!filename=:~0,4!"=="ABC0"` is wrong, it should be `if "!filename:~0,4!"=="ABC0"`

Comment: `if NOT` is the reason it would copy everything, but as far as I can tell there's more broken with your code than you say.

Comment: When comparing file names, always do it in a case-insensitive manner as Windows also treats files that way: `if /I "!filename:~0,4!"=="ABC0"` (the `not` is wrong, of course!)

Comment: after I remove NOT, it still not working.. and the file name is exactly all upper case. So case sensitive is not the issue.

Comment: Dear All, 
it work perfectly with ' if "!filename:~0,4!"=="ABC0" '.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust this code to your needs, particularly the hard coded TargetPath

```
@for %%x in (*.txt) do @call :MoveIt %%x
@exit /b 0

:MoveIt
@set filename=%1
@set filename=%filename:~0,4%
@if /i "%filename%" == "ABC0" @move "%1" "TargetPath"
@exit /b
```

To diagnose your original code, try this:

```
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set prompt=$G
@for %%x in (*.txt) do @(
    @set filename=%%~nx
    @echo filename==%filename%
    @echo %%~nx
    @echo %%x
)
```

I think the %%~nx wasn't doing what you expected and %filename% was empty. %%~nx was the file name with no extension. Not sure you can use the range notation in the if statement like that. I've only ever seen it used/working with the set command and that's the only documented usage I am aware of. I always avoid embedding multi-line blocks by converting the code to a subroutine call.

Comment: This work perfectly.. But may I know why I cannot use my above code ? After i remove "Not" it still not working..